# Implementation of Radix sort

Tags: c, radix-sort

I have been trying to write the Radix sort algorithm in C. 
When I run my code with base 10 it works fine for all inputs, however, with base 16 it sorts only the first 10 elements correctly. In addition, for any other base it is not working.
I would like to make an implementation that generalize for any base.

Here is the code a have so far, could you find any issues?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int size=32;
int getMax(int arr[], int n) {
    int mx = arr[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
       if (arr[i] > mx)
           mx = arr[i];
    return mx;
}

void countSort(int arr[], int n, int exp, int base) {
   int output[n]; 
   int i;
   int count[base];
   memset(count,0,sizeof count);   
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)
       count[(arr[i]/exp)%base]++;
   for (i=1;i<base;i++)
       count[i]=count[i]+count[i-1];
   for (i=n-1;i>=0;i--) {
      output[count[ (arr[i]/exp)%base ]-1]=arr[i];
      count[ (arr[i]/exp)%base ]--;
   }
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)
       arr[i]=output[i];
}

void radixsort(int arr[],int n,int base) {
  int exp;
  int m=getMax(arr,n);
  for (exp=1;m/exp>0;exp=exp*10)
    countSort(arr,n,exp,base);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {    
  int num,i=0,j,n,m;
  int *arr,*newarr=NULL;
  FILE *fp1;
  FILE *fp2;
  int base=atoi(argv[1]);
  fp1=fopen(argv[2],"r");
  if (fp1 == NULL) {
     printf("Warning:File does not exists;please enter valid file name");
     exit(0);
  }
  fp2=fopen(argv[3],"w");
  if (fp2 == NULL) {
       printf("Warning:File does not exists");
       exit(0);
  }
  arr= malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
  fprintf(fp2,"before sorting:");
  while(fscanf(fp1,"%d",&num)==1) {
    if(i<size) {
       arr[i]=num;
       i++;
       fprintf(fp2,"%d ",num);
       n=i;
    } else {
       newarr = malloc(sizeof(int)*2*size);
       for(m=0;m<size;m++) {
           newarr[m]=arr[m];
       }
       free(arr);
       size=size*2;
       arr=&newarr[0];
    }
  }
  radixsort(arr,n,base);
  fprintf(fp2,"\nAfter Sorting:");
  for (j=0;j<n;j++)
     fprintf(fp2,"%d ",arr[j]);

  fclose(fp1);
  fclose(fp2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why don't you just convert the number to base 10?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `for (exp=1;m/exp>0;exp=exp*10)`is the problem. I think you need to use `base` instead of `10`.

EDIT: I tried compiling and running this code and was not able to get it to work, even for base 10.

Comment: Sorry..i dont know why it is not running on your side but it woks fine when i executed it with base 10..

Comment: Does it work for other bases with the change I suggested?